# Search Chrome bookmarks with Windows 10 search box

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I use Chrome as by default browser, is it possible to search the Chrome bookmarks with the Windows 10 start menu search box? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did a test to add the Bookmarks file into the Windows Search> "Advanced Search Indexer Settings", however, after adding the Bookmarks files, we are still unable to search the Chrome bookmarks with the Windows 10 start menu search box. It seems the Windows failed to identify the file type of the bookmarks, so failed to open it.

So, as far as I'm concerned, it's not possible to search the Chrome bookmarks with the Windows 10 start menu search box directly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can search them using Windows native search. But one tip is the bookmarks are stored in `%Userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Bookmarks` file and if you have multiple profiles then you will get `Profile n` folders in User Data. There you can execute Sysinternals [strings.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings) to parse the strings at the end which are actually the bookmarks. You can copy this file to another chrome profile or User data folder on another PC.